# how to set a value Jtextfiled using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am creating a small application.In this application I have 2 jTextFields and a jButton1. I have done the program code . The application like convert alphabet to numeric. But I don't getting the values in jTextField2. *For example if I enter **abcd** I want to show th result in jTextField2 as **1234***
 Here I am putting my code from inside the jButton1 click.

Here is my code:

```
String text=jTextField1.getText();
        char letter;
for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
{
    letter = text.charAt(i);
    if(letter>='A' && letter<='Z')

        System.out.println(letter - 'A'+1);

    if(letter>='a' && letter<= 'z')
        System.out.println(letter - 'a'+1);
}
```

Comment: _if I enter abcd, th result in jTextField2 as 1234._ Why only `1234` as output. If input is `ABCD` then ?

Comment: create a new result string, keep appending the digits to that string. Outside the loop use `jTextField2.setText(string)` to set new text

Comment: @Satya if input is as ABCD same answer as 1234

Comment: @ritesht93 can you show a output in Jtextfield

Comment: A simple solution is 1. Take an String array contains letters `A-Z` or `a-z` (total 26). 2. If any char (take as string) matches to the one of string in this array then take the corresponding index.

Comment: @Satya It may take some more time. Just stuck on output mention I am getting the output but the main problem is I can't call the value in Jtextfield2

Comment: You've just put your output on the console using `System.out.println`. This doesn't put the output on your `jTextField2`. Use `jTextField2.setText(string)` as @ritesht93 said.

Comment: @STaefi It is ok. So how to call it ?

Comment: @Satya so What I need to do for it ?

Comment: @STaefi Showing error

Comment: And if input is `aAbB` then whats your expected output is it `1122`?

Comment: Show your code in an edit of your question. We can not chat here forever. We don't see how you are doing what we are saying.

Comment: It is mention in the code . as  **char letter**  as well as in the codition  **if**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Sample extends JFrame
{
    JTextField jTextField1, jTextField2;
    JButton jbtn;

Sample()
{       
    this.add(jTextField1=new JTextField(10));
    this.add(jTextField2=new JTextField(10));
    this.add(jbtn=new JButton("Convert"));

    jbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            String text=jTextField1.getText().toLowerCase();
            String result="";
            char letter;
            for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++)
            {
                letter=text.charAt(i);
                if(Character.isLetter(letter))
                    result+=Integer.toString(letter-'a'+1);
            }       
            jTextField2.setText(result);
            System.out.println("Final Output is: "+result);
        }
    });
}
 public static void main(String a[])
 {
    JFrame jf = new Sample();
    jf.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jf.setSize(400, 400);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```